# Problem with packages after Laravel namespace change to App\Models

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

So I used the namespace models shift to make the change from App to App\Models.

One of the packages in use (Ticketit) is calls App\User in it and I need a way to override this.

The offending file is:
\vendor\kordy\ticketit\src\Models\Agent.php

How can I override the "use App\user;" line there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am looking at in the [source code](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/blob/110d5d78fb997d0ba5d2ac6b9a4f9e31896976bd/src/Models/Agent.php#L5), that is hardcoded, so you cannot do anything then... I am not sure if you could "fake" the `App\User` to point to `App\Models\User` using composer but that would be nasty, same if you created a class on inside `app` folder with name `User` and it only extends the model like this:

```php
namespace App;

use App\Models\User as UserModel;

class User extends UserModel { }
```

That is nasty but maybe is a solution for you...

---

**Edit:** If you read carefully the [documentation](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/wiki/Make-sure-that-App%5CUser-exists) (please do so next time you use a package), it already says to make sure that `App\User` exists...

It tells you to do:

```php
namespace App;

class User extends Models\User {
    //leave this empty
}
```

For more info, see this [github issue](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit/issues/579) or create yourself a new one.